# Installing Stellaris_icdi_drivers Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

I have not been able to find anything on how to install these [drivers](https://www.ti.com/tool/STELLARIS_ICDI_DRIVERS#overview).  I have downloaded the zip file, and I checked the additional drivers tab in the software & update manager, but it does not find anything after extracting, or before.  They are for use with a Tiva C series launchpad.

Comment: (1) those drivers are for Windows (2) that's NOT how additional drivers work (3) ask the manufacturer/vendor about Linux support.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openocd

This package installed the drivers that I needed.

openocd - Open on-chip JTAG debug solution for ARM and MIPS systems